# WSO2 Identity Server Multilingual

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm working with Identity Server 5.1, my customer requiere support multiple languages, so the login authorization page and the recovery password function on the identity server are in english by default Is there a way to manage multiple languages?

For example I want to send the recovery password email, I know the email template is in this file email-­admin-­config.xml and it's ok if you only support one language but in my case I need support more languages is there a way or a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the features in the upcoming release of Identity Server (5.3.0). According to the [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2952) it is available from milestone 1 release of 5.3.0. You can download the milestone releases from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases).

Comment: Did you know what is the tentative target date for this release or where can I find this information?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The tentative release date for IS 5.3.0 is mid of Dec.